# File Upload Express MongoDB Multer

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

I'm trying to upload a image to my Express Rest Api. I'm using Multer to parse the multipart/form image. I would like to know whats best practice in saving images on the server or in the database. And how I can make this happen with Multer.

the user model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    avatar: {
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});
var User = module.exports = mongoose.model('user', userSchema, 'user');
module.exports.addUser = function(user, callback) {
    User.create(user, callback);
};
```

the user router:

```
import multer from 'multer';
var upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' })

import User from '../models/user.js';
router.post('/register', upload.single('avatar'), (req, res) => {           
    var user = req.body;
    user.avatar = req.file;   //img file in the req.file
    User.addUser(user, (err, user) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.json({
            success: true,
            user: user
        });
    })
});
```

This doesn't throw me any errors, but the image is not being uploaded to the db. Any Help would be appreciated. (the file is in the upload dir on the server with a 7-bit encoding)

Comment: Please do not try to upload images to any kind of database. This is an anti-pattern design decision.

Comment: May helpful in future for someone. here is a tutorial for nodejs mongdb file upload using multer tutorial: https://programmerblog.net/nodejs-file-upload-tutorial/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store images directly into database you have to use [fs.readFileSync](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options) to get the image as binary and then save it, note that `req.file.path` returns the full path of the uploaded file:

```
var user = req.body;
user.avatar.data = fs.readFileSync(req.file.path);
user.avatar.contentType = req.file.mimetype;

User.addUser(user, (err, user) => {
    ...
});
```

Keep in mind that storing images as strings that represent their urls could be better and easier than using the first approach, read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay) for more information

Comment: The question asks for "best-practice". I don't think that directly saving a whole image to database is a best-practice.

Comment: nice! yeah this works great, do you know how I can turn this back into a file as well?